# How to create an active menu for Ebook to call cell tag

Tags: cdf-format, stylesheet, docked-cell

I have some physics exercises done and I´d like to make an ebook in CDF with the explanations with simulations as well.

For these I look for some tips, and wolfram videos has a lot of it with Prof Eric Schulz.

http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=109&v=185

The code suggested by professor Schulz is this

```
CreateLinks[nb_] := Module[{tagList = {}},
  SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
  While[
   (* Keep moving cell by cell until the end of the notebook *) 
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
     FrontEnd`CellInformation[
      FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[nb]]] =!= $Failed,
   (* Extract the CellTags and store in tagList *)
   {If[(CellTags /. 
        Options[NotebookSelection[nb], "CellTags"]) =!= {}, 
     tagList = 
      Append[tagList, (CellTags /. 
         Options[NotebookSelection[nb], "CellTags"])]],
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]}];
  (* Build argument for ActionMenu *)
  MapThread[#1 :> {NotebookLocate[#1], 
      FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[
         "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}]} &, {tagList}]]
BuildDockedCell[chapter_, section_] := Module[{nb},
  nb = OpenSection[chapter, section];
  SetOptions[nb,DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Grid[{{
          ActionMenu[
           Row[{"Section ", chapter, ".", section}],
           CreateContentLinks[nb],
           ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, 
           BaseStyle -> {"MSG", 12}]}},
        Spacings -> {0.5, 0.5}, Alignment -> {Left, Top}],
     "DockedCell", Background -> GrayLevel[0.95]]]]
DeleteDockedCell[chapter_, section_] :=
 Module[{nb}, nb = OpenSection[chapter, section]; 
  SetOptions[nb, DockedCells -> Inherited]]
```

But after name the Cell (with tags) I tried these

```
BuildDockedCell[1, 1]
```

And Mathematica answear me that

```
SetOptions::sstm: "Argument OpenSection[1,1] is not a symbol or a stream."
```

Anyone can help me how to create this menu.

I also put a picture of how Eric Schulz book looks like.

[image]

Comment: Do you have function definitions for `OpenSection` and `CreateContentLinks`?

Comment: No, the code explained is just that